# how to increment a global variable in JavaScript every time a function runs in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, global-variables

This [adapted](https://codewithcurt.com/create-custom-html-form-for-google-sheets/) code:

```
var count = 0;


function AddRecord(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("F5");
  cell.setValue(name); 
  cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
  cell.setValue(count);
  count = count + 1;
}

function startForm() {
  var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddForm');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form, 'Add Record');


}

function addMenu() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom');
  menu.addItem('Add Record Form', 'startForm');
  menu.addToUi();

}

function onOpen(e) {

  addMenu();
}
```

works as expected, in that it writes the expected values, `name` and `count`, to their respective cells.  However, the value for `count` remains unchanged.  How is the `count` variable [incremented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758752/20193655) every time the `AddRecord` function executes?

This `const counter = ((count = 0) => () => count++)();` would seem to be at least the shortest solution suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When a function `AddRecord(name)` of Google Apps Script is run from `google.script.run.AddRecord(name)` of Javascript, unfortunately, `var count = 0;` is always run. By this, `count` is not changed from `0` every run of the function, and the value of `count` is not kept. I thought that this is the reason for your issue.

If you want to keep the count and when `AddRecord(name)` is run, you want to count up the value of `count`, how about the following modification? In this modification, I used PropertiesService.

#### Modified script:

**In this modification, the value of `count` is kept even when the dialog is closed.**

```js
function AddRecord(name) {
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var count = p.getProperty("count")
  count = count ? Number(count) : 0;

  // This is your current script.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("F5");
  cell.setValue(name);
  cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
  cell.setValue(count);
  count = count + 1;


  // Browser.msgBox(count); // If you use this, when "AddRecord" is run, you can see the current value of "count" in a dialog.

  p.setProperty("count", count);
}

// When you want to reset the value of "count", please run this function.
function resetCounter() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty("count");
}

function startForm() {
  var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddForm');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form, 'Add Record');
}
```

- In this modification, when `AddRecord` is run from Javascript, "count" is retrieved from PropertiesService and the value is increased and the updated value is stored in PropertiesService. By this, the value of "count" is kept.

#### Note:

- At the above-modified script, only Google Apps Script is used. As another direction, if you can also use the HTML side, how about the following modification? **In this modification, the value of `count` is cleared when the dialog is closed.**

  - Google Apps Script side:

    ```
      function AddRecord(name, count) {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data");
        var cell = sheet.getRange("F5");
        cell.setValue(name);
        cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
        cell.setValue(count);
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
      }

      function startForm() {
        var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddForm');
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form, 'Add Record');
      }
    ```
  - HTML side: This HTML is from your showing URL.

    ```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <base target="_top">
          <script>
          let count = 0;
          function AddRow()
          {
          var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
            count = e;
            console.log(count);
          }).AddRecord(name, count);
          }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          Name:  <input type="text" id="name" />
          <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()" />
        </body>
      </html>
    ```
  - When this script is run, when the button is clicked, `count` is increased. You can see it in the console of the browser.

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: When I saw your question, I thought that the duplicated question might be existing. But, I couldn't find it. So, as a sample modification, I proposed this modified script.